# How can I decide on the appropriate server to rent for my website?

Tags: server, vps

I am using nodejs in the backend. Users can share photos on the site. There is role-based authorization and authorized roles can also share articles and so on.  There are also content management panels for admins. I am using mysql as database. I am planning to install Nginx on the server I will buy.  For a start, there is a user base that will get a maximum of 200 clicks per day.  What would be the most suitable server features for this site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of opinion base questions are better to be asked on [Quora](https://www.quora.com/), [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/), as was told in [this SO discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255468/opinion-based-questions).

Anyways, 200 clicks per day is too few, you may even find a free server to upload it, take a look at [AWS free plans](https://aws.amazon.com/free/), [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/pricing).

In case you will host in a machine, you may need to use [forever library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) to runs your nodejs script continuously.

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice and I will be carefull about posting my question to the right place next time. Should I delete this question?